# Python code to convert a plt file into gcode with a specific format

Tags: python, python-2.7, g-code

I'd like to convert a set of coordinates from one file format to another. It's for a drawing machine, like a plotter.
The first file is a plt file that looks like this:

PU-3410,7784;PD-3373,-2281;PU16705,7978;PD16435,5325; (continues for thousands of coordinates)

and I'd like to convert it to another text file which would have this format:

G01 X-3410 Y7784 Z1000
G01 X-3373 Y-2281 Z0
G01 X16705 Y7978 Z1000
G01 X-16435 Y5325 Z0

PU means Pen Up (=Z1000 in Gcode) and PD is pen down (Z0).
I'm very new to python, all I know is how to code for Arduino. 
This piece of code would be so helpful. I've tried to understand how to open and write files but I'd too novice for this project so I thought I'd ask for help rather than give up. 
Really appreciate any help!
Cheers,
Pierre

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This might not be perfect, but I think I worked it out.

```
# Uncomment this to read the file... remember to change your variable names too
# with open('input_filename', 'r') as file:
#    file_text = file.read()

sample_text = 'PU-3410,7784;PD-3373,-2281;PU16705,7978;PD16435,5325;'

coordinates = sample_text.split(';') # Splits the overall text into smaller easier chunks

with open('output_filename', 'a+') as output_file: # Create file handler for output file
    for c in coordinates:
        if c[:2] == 'PU': # Checks the value of the first two characters, and if it is PU, use Z1000
            g_code = 'Z1000'
        else: # Use Z0 otherwise 
            g_code = 'Z0'
        c = c[2:] # chop off either PU or PD
        tokens = c.split(',') # Get the numbers
        if len(tokens) < 2: # if something isn't formatted right, exit.
            break
        output_file.write("G01 X{0} Y{1} {2}\n".format(tokens[0], tokens[1], g_code))
```

There are a few key assumption I made to take note of:

1) There are no formatting errors in the input file
2) All lines will begin with G01
3) I don't know the full specs so other things may be off

Comment: Nice work, although you're opening the output file for each coordinate. It might be better to open the output file and then iterate over the coordinates.

Comment: Wow that worked. Thx! I get how you did so I’ll try to rewrite it myself to make sure I learn.